# Searching for an int inside a string user input

Tags: java, string, integer, string-matching

I am currently doing an assignment for class and I would like to know how to find an integer inside a string input. So far in the code I have created a way to exit the loop. Please don't give me code just give me some ideas. Keep in mind that I am quite new to java so please bear with me. Thanks. 
EDIT: I forgot to mention that the string input should be like "woah123" and it should find only the "123" portion. Sorry

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleTheInt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int EXIT = 0;
        while(EXIT == 0)
        {
            Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is your sentence?");
            String sentence = kbReader.next();
            if(sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            {
                break;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, if the string is `"abc123efg"` the program should find `123`?

Comment: You can either use regex or iterate through each index of the String and check if its a number or not.

Comment: yes sorry i didnt clarify
edit : unfortunately i havent learned regex so i do not know how to use that

Comment: Check out a [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Please change `int EXIT = 0; while(EXIT == 0) {` to `while(true) {` I get a twitch in my left eye every time I read it. If you set EXIT to 0 and then test for 0 you get true, so may as well just test for true.

Answer (score 2):

For learning purpose what you can do is traverse the whole string and check only for the digits. In this case you will also learn how to check char-by-char in a string if in future you may require this also you will get the digits of that string. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: @TheLostMind: He is new to Java and wants to learn, considering that the answer is given.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do...

```
 Replace all non numeric characters with empty string using \\D and String.replaceAll function
 Parse your  string (after replacing)  as integer using Integer.parseInt()
```

Edited after Christian's comment :

```
replaceAll() function replaces occurances of particular String (Regex is first argument) with that of the second argument String.. 
\\D is used to select everything except the numbers in the String. So, the above 2 lines combined will give "1234" if your String is "asas1234" . 

Now , Integer.parseInt is used to convert a String to integer.. It takes a String as argument and returns an Integer.
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: I am not the downvoter but as OP stated, _"Please don't give me code just give me some ideas"_

Comment: ok.. My bad.. changed code to algorithm.. :P .. I just thought that OP would find it difficult to code (@ OP no disrespect.. :) )

Comment: Not saying that you **must** post pseudocode, posting code is OK but you should explain what you are doing, what is each method doing, since I don't think OP had used these before.

Comment: Hi LostMind apparently I didn't make myself clear enough(my fault sorry) but I would like to keep the letters inside the return. Sorry for not making this clear in my question.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but you could make a copy of the `String`, then apply @TheLostMind code.

Comment: @user3059540 - .. Yes.. You can store the value of the replaced String in a different variable (reference) and then parse it as Integer. Your original String will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not asking for code , I am giving you some suggestions.

1. Use regex in string method to find the numbers and to remove all the
   non numbers.
2. Parse the string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your assignment "is" a regex assignment, I suggest you do it the non-regex way. i.e, by reading character by character and checking for integers or reading the string and converting to a char array and process.

I'm not sure what your teacher intends you to do, but there are two ways-

1. Read character by character and filter the numbers by their ASCII code. Use [BuffferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read from standard input. And use [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) method. Figure out the ASCII code range for numbers by experimenting.
2. Read the entire String at once(using either Scanner or BufferedReader) and see what you can do from the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)(as in the methods available for String).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) : \d+

```
String value = "abc123";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
int i = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
System.out.println(i);
```

output

123